# Creating 2D bins in R

Tags: r, 2d, bins

I have coordinate data in R, and I would like to determine a distribution of where my points lie. The entire space of points is a square of side length 100.

I'd like to assign points to different segments on the square, for example rounded to the nearest 5. I've seen examples using `cut` and `findinterval` but i'm not sure how to use this when creating a 2d bin.

Actually, what I want to be able to do is smooth the distribution so there are not huge jumps in between neighboring regions of the grid.

For example (this is just meant to illustrate the problem):

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(2000, 0, 100)
y <- runif(2000, 0, 100)
plot(y~x)
points( x = 21, y = 70, col = 'red', cex = 2, bg = 'red')
```

the red point is clearly in a region that by chance hasn't had many other points, so the density here would be a jump from the density of the neighbouring regions, I'd like to be able to smooth this out

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the binned data using the `bin2` function in the `ash` library.

Regarding the problem of the sparsity of data in the region around the red point, one possible solution is with the average shifted histogram. It bins your data after shifting the histogram several times and averaging the bin counts. This alleviates the problem of the bin origin. e.g., imagine how the number of points in the bin containing the red point changes if the red point is the topleft of the bin or the bottom right of the bin.

```
library(ash)
bins <- bin2(cbind(x,y))
f <- ash2(bins, m = c(5,5))

image(f$x,f$y,f$z)
contour(f$x,f$y,f$z,add=TRUE)
```

If you would like smoother bins, you could try increasing the argument `m`, which is a vector of length 2 controlling the smoothing parameters along each variable.

```
f2 <- ash2(bins, m = c(10,10))
image(f2$x, f2$y, f2$z)
contour(f2$x,f2$y,f2$z,add=TRUE)
```

Compare `f` and `f2`
[image]

The binning algorithm is implemented in fortran and is very fast.

Comment: By the way, ash is a computationally efficient alternative to using kdes, which are generally better density estimators than histogram based methods. It is just worth noting the logic behind the thought process. It is also worth considering that most kde implementations that are fast will use a binned estimates of the density estimate.

Comment: good eye. was a typo. corrected now

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use `ggplot2`, there are some nice options.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x,y)) + geom_bin2d()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x,y)) + stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon")
```

[image]

Update: To calculate the 2d binning, you could use a 2d (bivariate) normal kernel density smoothing:

```
library(KernSmooth)
bins <- bkde2D(as.matrix(data.frame(x, y)), bandwidth = c(2, 2), gridsize = c(25L, 25L))
```

which can also be plotted as

```
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(bins$fhat), aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + geom_raster()
```

[image]

The `bins` object contains the `x` and `y` values and normalised density `fhat`. Play with the gridsize (number of grid points in each direction) and bandwidth (smoothing scale) to get what you're after.

Comment: how do i extract the bins here? and the probability assigned to each bin?

Comment: @dimebucker91 I agree, the problem with this ggplot function is that it's not very flexible. For example using bins to control geom_point size.