# Efficiently plotting hundreds of millions of points in R

Tags: r, plot, graphics, strange-attractor

Is `plot()` the most efficient way to plot 100 million or so data points in R?
I'd like to plot a bunch of these [Clifford Attractors](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/clifford/). Here's an example of one I've downscaled from a very large image:

[image: A Clifford attractor]

[Here](https://pastebin.com/yFvxW42t) is a link to some code that I've used to plot a very large 8K (7680x4320) images.

It doesn't take long to generate 50 or 100 million points (using Rcpp), nor to get the hex value for the colour + transparency, but the actual plotting and saving to disk is **extremely** slow.

- Is there a faster way to plot (and save) all these points?
- Is R just a bad tool for this job?
- What tools would you use to plot billions points, even if you couldn't fit them all in to ram?
- How would one have made a very high resolution plot of this type (colour + transparency) with say 1990's software and hardware?

**Edit: code used**

```
# Load packages
library(Rcpp)
library(viridis)

# output parameters
output_width = 1920 * 4
output_height = 1080 * 4
N_points = 50e6
point_alpha = 0.05 #point transperancy

# Attractor parameters
params <- c(1.886,-2.357,-0.328, 0.918)

# C++ function to rapidly generate points
cliff_rcpp <- cppFunction(
    "
    NumericMatrix cliff(int nIter, double A, double B, double C, double D) {
    NumericMatrix x(nIter, 2);
    for (int i=1; i < nIter; ++i) {
    x(i,0) = sin(A*x(i-1,1)) + C*cos(A*x(i-1,0));
    x(i,1) = sin(B*x(i-1,0)) + D*cos(B*x(i-1,1));
    }
    return x;
    }"
)

# Function for mapping a point to a colour
map2color <- function(x, pal, limits = NULL) {
    if (is.null(limits))
        limits = range(x)
    pal[findInterval(x,
                     seq(limits[1], limits[2], length.out = length(pal) + 1),
                     all.inside = TRUE)]
}

# Obtain matrix of points
cliff_points <- cliff_rcpp(N_points, params[1], params[2], params[3], params[4])

# Calculate angle between successive points
cliff_angle <- atan2(
    (cliff_points[, 1] - c(cliff_points[-1, 1], 0)),
    (cliff_points[, 2] - c(cliff_points[-1, 2], 0))
)

# Obtain colours for points
available_cols <-
    viridis(
        1024,
        alpha = point_alpha,
        begin = 0,
        end = 1,
        direction = 1
    )

cliff_cols <- map2color(
    cliff_angle,
    c(available_cols, rev(available_cols))
)


# Output image directly to disk
jpeg(
    "clifford_attractor.jpg",
    width = output_width,
    height = output_height,
    pointsize = 1,
    bg = "black",
    quality = 100

)
    plot(
        cliff_points[-1, ],
        bg = "black",
        pch = ".",
        col = cliff_cols
    )

dev.off()
```

Comment: Maybe use `image` instead of `plot`?

Comment: @KarstenW. I thought about that, but I would have to map the millions of points on to a pixel location myself and determine the correct colour when 2 or more points end up on the same pixel. Something I don't how to do efficiently, but could probably play around with it.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how does the speed of `png()` compare with that of `jpeg()`?

Comment: About dealing with several points on the same pixel, you could bin the points per pixel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822718/creating-2d-bins-in-r

Comment: @BenBolker, I haven't compared timings, but both are very slow.

Comment: @Pere, I'll try have a look at that, but it might be difficult to get the correct colour for each bin. The bin colour is not just a function of the number of points in each bin. In he plot, the point colour is a function of the angle between the last 2 points.

Comment: Although I am an old R addict, I don't think this is the way to go... Googling leads me to this post with Julia: https://hackernoon.com/drawing-2-7-billion-points-in-10s-ecc8c85ca8fa

Comment: Thanks @EricLecoutre, informative link. The slides referenced, https://www.slideshare.net/continuumio/visualizing-a-billion-points-w-bokeh-datashader which looks fantastic but unfortunately there is no interface for R. Explanation of why: https://github.com/bokeh/datashader/issues/304

Comment: Ideally you want an opengl solution, something that can handle this. I use plotly specifically for this purpose using scattergl

Comment: This post is related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213225/processing-vector-to-raster-faster-with-r. Although, I think `raster::rasterize()` is slower.

Comment: The problem can be parallelized at different levels. One approach would be to create images of sub-regions and join them afterwards.

Comment: @Florian that is a great idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've recently discovered the [Scattermore](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scattermore/index.html) package for R which is about an order of magnitude faster than R's standard plot function. `scattermoreplot()` takes ~2 minutes to plot 100m points with colour and transparency, while `plot()` takes around half an hour.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently exploring **datashader** (http://www.datashader.org). If you are willing to work with python, this could be an elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: Here's a comprehensive attractor explorer using datashader: https://anaconda.org/jbednar/datashaderattractors/notebook ; you can set the resolution to whatever you like.  It could be made much more efficient by plotting it in batches (generate a batch, plot a batch, repeat), but right now it favors simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe geom_hex() from the ggplo2 package can be a solution?
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_hex.html

Comment: Hi @Sara, this would not achieve the intended effect. I want to preserve as much detail as possible, not bin the pixels.