# R: what's the most efficient way to export in png?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R, my go-to command to export a plot generated with ggplot in png is (for instance):

```
png(filename="fig.png", res = 800, width = 11.69, height = 8.27, units = "in")
par (bg=NA)
fig
dev.off()
```

In my case, `fig` is a grid (generated with `ggarrange`) of 4 x 4  plots, and it can take a while to export it. Is there any more efficient method to do the export?

(I have noticed it is much faster to directly store any plot generated by ggplot in an object without rendering it. I am afraid here that the call `fig` triggers the whole rendering. Maybe I can avoid it?)

Comment: You can reduce resolution with the argument `res`

Comment: `ggsave`? It's in `ggplot2` and intended to export `ggplot` objects

Comment: I have some trouble using `system.time()` on the few lines hereabove but seems roughly similar. Anyway, `ggsave` is definitely more elegant and I didn't know it, cheers!

Comment: @francoiskroll ; unfortunately it can take time to plot ([even in base r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122970/efficiently-plotting-hundreds-of-millions-of-points-in-r)). ps ggsave is a wrapper for various device output functions, including png, so as you found it wont be faster.

Comment: Yeah, I have been looking around and cannot find any decent solution unfortunately. Such a shame, my code is running so fast now thanks to the amazing `data.table` package but gets stuck when exporting. It really take ages at a decent resolution. Would other format than `png` make any difference?

Comment: I don't know, sorry -- I think png is usually pretty fast. What sort of plot are you doing - why does it take so long? i.e. can you aggregate / plot a sample etc?